# Block Matrix Multiplication

Tags: syntax

I have

```
a = {{-1}, {0}, {0}}
b = IdentityMatrix[3]
c = {a, b}
d = {{7}, {2}, {0}, {0}}
```

and would like to compute

```
e = c.d
```

but I get the error "Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered". I have no idea why this isn't working. Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @Mahdi The desired output would be the column vector {{-5},{0},{0}}

Comment: Your `c` is dimensionally inconsistent (check it). I suspect what you want is `Join[a, b, 2]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I was trying to create a matrix "c" using block notation (I usually use matlab). It looks like I should have made c = {{a,b}} and then use ArrayFlatten. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that dimension of matrices are not compatible.

```
 a = {{-1}, {0}, {0}}
 Dimensions[a]
 (* {3, 1} *)
 b = IdentityMatrix[3]
 Dimensions[b]
 (* {3, 3} *)
 c = {a, b}
 Dimensions[c]
 (* {2, 3} *)
 d = {{7}, {2}, {0}, {0}}
 Dimensions[d]
 (* {4, 1} *)
```

If you multiply a $m \times n$ matrix by a $n \times l$ matrix, you get a $m \times l$ matrix. You should have

```
 c = {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
 Dimensions[Transpose@c]
 (* {3,4} *)
 d = {{7}, {2}, {0}, {0}};
 Dimensions[d]
 (* {4,1} *)
```

Then:

```
 Dot[Transpose@c, d]
 (* {{-5}, {0}, {0}} *)
```